# Reuse an exisiting numpy array or create a new one?

Tags: python, performance, numpy

In iterative algorithms, it is common to use large numpy arrays many times. I want to fill value into a big existing numpy array, but I found create a new array is even faster.

```
>>>import numpy as np
>>>a=np.arange(10000)
>>>b=a.copy()
>>>%timeit b=a+a   # Every time create a new array
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.59 µs per loop
>>>%timeit b[:]=a+a  # Use existing array
100000 loops, best of 3: 13.3 µs per loop
>>>%timeit np.copyto(b,a+a)  # Another way to use existing array
100000 loops, best of 3: 13.4 µs per loop
```

- If there is any faster way to reuse the existing array? (for example, `b` above)
- If no such way, why create a new array is faster?
- Is there any drawback about recreate a new array every time? I hesitate about it, becuase my data is big and I need to assign it with different value in every iteration.

Comment: I believe the results are explained by the fact that when you do `b[:]=a+a`, it first computes a+a and puts that in an array, then assigns that array to the memory in b.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `np.copyto(b,a);b+=a` is faster, but not the fastest way.
- `np.add(a,a,b)` is the best choice for now, 100000 loops, best of 3: 8.66 µs per loop.

Maybe `b[:]=a+a` will genarate some temporary calculation spaces? I don't konw. But use "+=, -=, *=, add" these ufuns won't be wrong.